# How to create an SAPI / API in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I found some posts below,but that can not work for my case.

[How to create a REST API for a Ruby application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660453/how-to-create-a-rest-api-for-a-ruby-application)

[Ruby on Rails with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426467/ruby-on-rails-with-rest-api)

But they all telling to use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) instead of [Rails framework](http://rubyonrails.org/)

But, That is not possible in my application,as It is bigger and most of the part is using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) features.

[Server Application Programming Interface (SAPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface) is a part my application . application is wast and most of the part is already developed in [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).

Can anybody help me how should I create [Server Application Programming Interface (SAPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface) using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)?

Comment: I am using rails version 3.1 and ruby version 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on operation you want your API allows to do.

For example there is gem [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) for RoR that generate resource methods for models.

You just need to create such controller:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
    respond_to :xml, :json
end
```

and now you have API methods that can create, read, update and destroy records in your Projects table, and support two formats xml and json!

I think it is very convenient, but it depends on your purposes.